# Execute a method corresponding to a received String

Tags: java, string

I'm new to Java and I want to execute a method corresponding to a String I receive.
In Python I would just do this

```
myString = "create"
options = {
    "create": self.create,
    "delete": self.delete,
    "list_jobs": self.list_jobs
}
options[myString]()
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: Look into reflection.

Comment: Take a look at the Java Reflection tutorial at Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: It is possible. You have to refine the words you use in your queries when doing your research on the net

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have anything like that, but you can use a `switch`.

```
switch (myString) {

    case "create":
        self.create;
        break;
    case "delete":
        self.delete;
        break;
    case "list_jobs":
        self.list_jobs;
        break;
}
```

Note that you probably should use more complicated object oriented concepts, but for simple programs this works fine.

Comment: This is fine for a specific set of methods and a single class. For a more generic (and proper) approach, use reflection.

Comment: Hmm yeah... It would work for his case though...

Comment: We don't know if this is just a sample of the real problem...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Map<String, Runnable>`.

```
Map<String, Runnable> commandTable = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();

static void initCommandTable() {
    commandTable.add("foo", new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //implement foo command
             ...
        });

    commandTable.add("bar", new Runnable() { 
        @Override
        public void run() {
             //implement bar command
             ...
        });

    ...
}

void doCommand(String command) {
    commandTable.get(command).run();
}
```

Yeah, Java is a lot more verbose than Python.  But we knew that already.